# Get number of entries between two words

Tags: r

Hi I can't find a solution to prepare my data.

At the moment I have two Vectors like below and would like to match those to the corresponding titles in an extra column.
Which Names match with which title is indicates by an entry in the name data called "Top"

```
name <- c("Top", "Name1", "Name2", "Top", "Name3", "Top", "Name4", "Name5")
title <- c("Title1", "Title2", "Title3")
```

What the result should look like:

```
Title1   Name1
Title1   Name2
Title2   Name3
Title3   Name4
Title3   Name5
```

An idea is to get the number of names between the "Top" entries and replicate the titles according to those numbers but how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
name <- c("Top", "Name1", "Name2", "Top", "Name3", "Top", "Name4", "Name5")
title <- c("Title1", "Title2", "Title3")
pos <- which(name %in% "Top")
for (i in length(name):1) {
  if(i %in% which(name %in% "Top")) {
    pos <- pos[pos != i]
  }
  else {
    print(paste(title[length(pos)], name[i], sep = " "))
  }
}
#> [1] "Title3 Name5"
#> [1] "Title3 Name4"
#> [1] "Title2 Name3"
#> [1] "Title1 Name2"
#> [1] "Title1 Name1"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Obviously, you can collect the result in list, instead of printing it.

Answer (score 3):

We could use an `if` statement:

1. group by Top beginning rows
2. ungroup and apply an if condition using `str_detect` which detects the number in `title` and checks if it is in id
3. if true `paste` Title + id
4. finally filter to remove `Top` rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id = cumsum(name=="Top")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Title = if(str_detect(title, "\\d+") %in% id) {paste0("Title",id)}) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(name, "Name"))
```

```
 Title  name 
  <chr>  <chr>
1 Title1 Name1
2 Title1 Name2
3 Title2 Name3
4 Title3 Name4
5 Title3 Name5
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

```r
g <- gsub('[0-9]+', '', name)
s <- rle(g)

data.frame(Title = rep(title, s$l[s$v == "Name"]),
           Name = name[g == "Name"])

   Title  Name
1 Title1 Name1
2 Title1 Name2
3 Title2 Name3
4 Title3 Name4
5 Title3 Name5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` using `cumsum`

```
i1 <- name == 'Top'
setNames(stack(setNames(split(name[!i1], cumsum(i1)[!i1]), title))[2:1], 
    c("Title", "Name"))
   Title  Name
1 Title1 Name1
2 Title1 Name2
3 Title2 Name3
4 Title3 Name4
5 Title3 Name5
```